# Has `scenarioResult.isFailed()` been removed in (typings) CucumberJS 1.x to 2.x

Tags: typescript-typings, cucumberjs

I'm currently migrating a Typescript CucumberJS 1.3 project to CucumberJS 2.2. this also means an update from `@types/cucumber` version `1.3.1` to `2.0.1`.

In my After hook is now see that I can't use `isFailed()` anymore, see below, or am I missing something?

```js
// 1.3.x
this.After((scenario: HookScenario): void {
    // logs scenario.isFailed() = true / false
    console.log('scenario.isFailed() = ', scenario.isFailed());
}

// 2.x.x
this.After((scenarioResult:HookScenarioResult): void => {
    // logs scenario.status = '{string} status'
    console.log('scenarioResult.status = ', scenarioResult.status);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your [release notes](https://github.com/wswebcreation/protractor-cucumber-typescript-boilerplate/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md),

```js
// 1.3.x
this.After(function (scenario: HookScenario): void {
    // logs scenario.isFailed() = true / false
    console.log('scenario.isFailed() = ', scenario.isFailed());
}

// 2.x.x
this.After(function (scenarioResult: HookScenarioResult): void {
    // logs scenario.status = '{string} status'
    console.log('scenarioResult.status = ', scenarioResult.status);
    
    // Changed to
    console.log('scenario failed = ', scenarioResult.status === 'failed');  
});
```

Comment: lol, that are my **own release** notes of **my own boilerplate project**. I've put it there because I couldn't find an official answer in the docs of CucumberJS

Comment: Lol...:s...I am working on something similar and I found this issue and after searching on google, I found your release note so I just answer to your issue :D